# TypeError: storage._handleFile is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongoose, multer-gridfs-storage

[image: This the error screenshot when i was working with image upload with multer-gridfs-storage]

I want to retrieve an image from the mongodb database using nodejs and mongoose as a ORM. I got this error when i was trying to retreive image from database. I have used multer-gridfs-storage for storing the image to mongodb

Comment: add your code mate ... Its quite difficult to say something based on just the error

Comment: the code is too complex and to difficult to post the part so do you have any idea about this error

Comment: are you storing the whole image into the database ?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell but you're probably using:

```
{ storage: { storage: diskStorage(...) }}
```

It should be

```
{ storage: diskStorage(...) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a little developer tip mate, using multer-gridfs-storage you can upload the whole image into the data base . That means the database will be very heavy in a little time. So let's say after a quite a long time you will need to make a backup. So the backup time will be massive mate.

So my recommendation is that you use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) - npm. Just multer because using that you can still upload the image but not to the database. Instead you can store the image into your server by creating a dedicated folder for all your image and upload all incoming images there. To reference the image into a certain object, you can store the image name instead of the whole image. Thus the database size will be not increased rapidly